# Conditional check with str.endswith()

Tags: python, conditional-expressions

I have the following string

```
mystr = "foo.tsv"
```

or

```
mystr = "foo.csv"
```

Given this condition, I expect the two strings above to always print "OK".
But why it fails?

```
if not mystr.endswith('.tsv') or not mystr.endswith(".csv"):
    print "ERROR"
else:
    print "OK"
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Note that `endswith()` also accepts a tuple: `if not mystr.endswith(('.tsv', ".csv")):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is failing because `mystr` cannot end with both `.csv` as well as `.tsv` at the same time.

So one of the conditions amounts to False, and when you use `not` in that it becomes `True` and hence you get `ERROR`. What you really want is -

```
if not (mystr.endswith('.tsv') or mystr.endswith(".csv")):
```

Or you can use the `and` version using [De-Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) , which makes `not (A or B)` into `(not A) and (not B)`

---

Also, as noted in the comments in the question, [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) accepts a tuple of suffixes to check for (so you do not even need the `or` condition). Example -

```
if not mystr.endswith(('.tsv', ".csv")):
```